# Git branch checkout history: back and forward

Tags: git

Can I navigate to the previous branch I was on without specifying its name?

For example, I work on branch `A`, then I checkout `B`. I want to return back to `A` by saying something like "go back" but not typing `git checkout A`.

And same question for "go forward".